# Protobuf type for bigquery TIMESTAMP field

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am streaming data to bigquery from Golang using the new [Storage API](http://cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/apiv1beta2). The schema of my bigquery table contains a TIMESTAMP field as follows:

```
bq mk -t mydataset.mytable name:string,lastseen:timestamp
```

Separately I have defined a protocol buffer like this:

```
message Row {
    string Name = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp LastSeen = 3;
}
```

However, when I submit this data to BigQuery, I get the following error:

```
rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = The proto field mismatched with BigQuery field at tutorial_Row.LastSeen, the proto field type message, BigQuery field type TIMESTAMP
```

It seems that the `google.protobuf.Timestamp` protobuf does not correspond to the TIMESTAMP type in bigquery. This makes sense because the bigquery docs say that a TIMESTAMP contains a timezone, but `google.protobuf.Timestamp` does not contain a timezone. But which protocol buffer then should I use?

I'm using code derived from [this repository](https://github.com/alexflint/bigquery-storage-api-example), which looks like this:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    storage "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/apiv1beta2"
    "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter/adapt"
    storagepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/bigquery/storage/v1beta2"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
    timestamppb "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"
)

const (
    project = "myproject"
    dataset = "mydataset"
    table   = "mytable2"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    // the data we will stream to bigquery
    var rows = []*Row{
        {Name: "John Doe", Age: 104, LastSeen: timestamppb.Now()},
        {Name: "Jane Doe", Age: 69, LastSeen: timestamppb.Now()},
        {Name: "Adam Smith", Age: 33, LastSeen: timestamppb.Now()},
    }

    // create the bigquery client
    client, err := storage.NewBigQueryWriteClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // create the write stream
    // a COMMITTED write stream inserts data immediately into bigquery
    resp, err := client.CreateWriteStream(ctx, &storagepb.CreateWriteStreamRequest{
        Parent: fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/datasets/%s/tables/%s", project, dataset, table),
        WriteStream: &storagepb.WriteStream{
            Type: storagepb.WriteStream_COMMITTED,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("CreateWriteStream: ", err)
    }

    // get the stream by calling AppendRows
    stream, err := client.AppendRows(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("AppendRows: ", err)
    }

    // get the protobuf descriptor for our row type
    var row Row
    descriptor, err := adapt.NormalizeDescriptor(row.ProtoReflect().Descriptor())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("NormalizeDescriptor: ", err)
    }

    // serialize the rows
    var opts proto.MarshalOptions
    var data [][]byte
    for _, row := range rows {
        buf, err := opts.Marshal(row)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("protobuf.Marshal: ", err)
        }
        data = append(data, buf)
    }

    // send the rows to bigquery
    err = stream.Send(&storagepb.AppendRowsRequest{
        WriteStream: resp.Name,
        Rows: &storagepb.AppendRowsRequest_ProtoRows{
            ProtoRows: &storagepb.AppendRowsRequest_ProtoData{
                // protocol buffer schema
                WriterSchema: &storagepb.ProtoSchema{
                    ProtoDescriptor: descriptor,
                },
                // protocol buffer data
                Rows: &storagepb.ProtoRows{
                    SerializedRows: data, // serialized protocol buffer data
                },
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("AppendRows.Send: ", err)
    }

    // get the response, which will tell us whether it worked
    _, err = stream.Recv()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("AppendRows.Recv: ", err)
    }

    log.Println("done")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, the backend doesn't decode proto Timestamp messages properly.

Quickest resolution answer: send int64 type, populate as epoch microseconds.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#data_type_conversions

Comment: do you know if there are plans to support the wellknown Timestamp in the backend as a valid input in the future?

Comment: There are plans.  I went and created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227333616 so there's something external for tracking this request.